# Select one field from a measurement filtered by another fields value in InfluxDB

Tags: database, flux, influxdb-2

I'm trying to select a field from a measurement depending on another fields value (with Flux)

A SQL-Statement would look like this:

```
SELECT column1 FROM table WHERE column2 > 100;
```

Thx in advance for any help

Comment: Did you ever find an answer? Amerousful's answer doesn't seem to work - it filters out the field you're interested in.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if this kills performance (specifically the `fieldsAsCols` call), but it works. It filters by a tag, then pivots the table so that all fields become their own columns, then it filters by `field1`. Finally it takes the last row (if `field2` exists on it).

```
import "influxdata/influxdb/schema"

from(bucket: "my-bucket-name")
  |> range(start: 2015-07-17T20:32:58.662703915Z, stop: 2022-12-17T20:32:58.662703915Z)
  |> filter(fn: (r) => r["_measurement"] == "my-measurement-name")
  |> filter(fn: (r) => r.myTagName == "2")
  |> schema.fieldsAsCols()
  |> filter(fn: (r) => r.field1 == "some_random_field_value")
  |> last(column: "field2")
  |> yield()
```

This would be equivalent to:

```
SELECT field2 WHERE field1 = "some_random_field_value";
```

Answer (score -1):

Please check official documentation. There is many example and explanation for Flux:

- https://docs.influxdata.com/influxdb/v1.8/flux/get-started/query-influxdb/
- https://docs.influxdata.com/influxdb/v2.0/upgrade/v1-to-v2/migrate-cqs/#convert-influxql-continuous-queries-to-flux

```
  from(bucket: "bucket")
      |> range(start: v.timeRangeStart, stop: v.timeRangeStop)
      |> filter(fn: (r) => r["_measurement"] == "table")
      |> filter(fn: (r) => 
              r["_field"] == "column1" and 
              r["column2"] > 100
            )
```

Comment: This only works if column2 is a tag. What if it's not a tag, but a field?